# Unity C# как освобождать оперативную память

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть сцена, со множеством на ней объектов, спрайтов и анимаций. По окончанию работы над приложением, заметил, что приложение занимает больше 200 мб оперативной памяти. Что не очень хорошо, для мобильных устройств. Как освобождать оперативную память от объектов с которыми не происходит взаимодействия? Пытался удалять при помощи "Destroy();" но оперативная память не прибавлялась как в "Profiler" так и на реальном устройстве "SetActive" тоже результатов не дал. Освобождает память только открытие новой сцены, но это не выход из положения.
Спасибо.

Comment: А, что там слышно по поводу GC.Collect(...) ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx - по моему, это Ваш случай

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов нельзя его использовать.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а почему нельзя после Destroy() принудительно вызвать сборщик мусора?

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов он медленный. Это решение симптомов, а не проблемы.

Comment: @Suvitruf, да он медленный, но по-моему там просят очистить память.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов память должна сама очищаться. Если там лики, то `GC.Collect` не поможет.

Comment: Всем спасибо за разъяснения!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Тут уже советовали `GC.Collect`. Так вот, НЕЛЬЗЯ его использовать. Во-первых, потому что это решение симптомов, а не проблемы. Во-вторых, эта штука жутко тормозная.
2. Нужно понять, что же это висит в памяти.
3. Почитать статьи вроде [этой](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/performance-optimization/optimizing-garbage-collection-unity-games).
4. Пока приложение работает, посмотрите что и где выделяется в [Deep Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerMemory.html).
5. Посмотреть, к примеру, в сторону [`UnloadUnusedAssets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets.html).